# How to limit my swagger definition array to be either 0 or 3

Tags: openapi, swagger-2.0

I have my swagger definition like :

```
someDef:
    type: object
    properties:
      enable:
        type: boolean
        default: false
      nodes:
        type: array
        maxItems: 3
        items:
          type: object
          properties:
            ip:
              type: string
              default: ''
```

My nodes are array and it has maxitems: 3.
I want my nodes items length to be either 0 or 3.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Either 0 or 3 items" can be defined in OpenAPI 3.x (`openapi: 3.x.x`) but not in OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`).

#### OpenAPI 3.x

You can use `oneOf` in combination with `minItems` and `maxItems` to define the "either 0 or 3 items" condition:

```yaml
# openapi: 3.0.0

nodes:
  type: array
  items:
    type: object
    properties:
      ip:
        type: string
        default: ''
  oneOf:
    - minItems: 0
      maxItems: 0
    - minItems: 3
      maxItems: 3
```

Note while `oneOf` is part of the OpenAPI 3.0 Specification (i.e. you can write API definitions that include `oneOf`), actual tooling support for `oneOf` may vary.

#### OpenAPI 2.0

OAS 2 does not have a way to define "either 0 or 3 items". The most you can do is to use `maxItems: 3` to define the upper limit.